# Is there a generalization of braided monoidal category without the isomorphism requirement?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Is there a generalization of the notion of braided monoidal category that does not force the braiding $\gamma$ to be an isomorphism? I mean, it is of course possible to define such a kind of category, but is this a common notion with an established name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Day, Panchadcharam, and Street have a [paper](http://science.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/laxcentre.pdf) on lax braidings, though I don't think it could be called a *common* notion. Anyway, "lax" seems to be the obvious terminology to try here.

Comment: *Brian Day, Elango Panchadcharam, and Ross Street.

Answer (score 8):

This generalization has also been studied by Victoria Lebed, which she called "pre-braided" in her thesis [Objets tressés: une étude unificatrice de structures algébriques et une catégorification des tresses virtuelles](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Elebed/thesis_LEBED.pdf) (title in French but most of the text is in English).  Actually, Lebed motivates an analogous generalization of the notion of *braided object* in a monoidal category, defined as an object $A$ equipped with a (not necessarily invertible) morphism $\gamma : A \otimes A \to A \otimes A$ satisfying the Yang-Baxter equation.  One advantage of dropping the invertibility assumption is that it permits studying *idempotent braidings*, in particular see her papers:

- [Cohomology of idempotent braidings, with applications to factorizable monoids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08081)
- [Plactic monoids: a braided approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.05768)

for some very interesting examples of idempotent braidings in $(\mathbf{Set},\times,1)$.